# how to copy a directory (folder and its contents) to another directory?

Tags: linux, shell, cp

Here is my file structure:

```
- someDirA
  -  folderOne
  -  folderTwo
     - somefile.txt
     - someotherfile.txt

- someDirB
  -  somefolder
```

What I want 'someDirB' to look like:

```
- someDirB
  - somefolder
  - folderTwo
    - somefile.txt
    - someotherfile.txt
```

I just want to copy someDirA's folderTwo(folder and all its contents) into someDirB. Both directories are in separate paths.

Comment: You might find `cp -a` useful, as it adds to `-r` extra options to preserve file attributes in the copied files. Also `cp -ua` will copy only updated files if you need to repeat the copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cp -r /path/to/someDirA/folderTwo /path/to/someDirB/`

The `-r` option to `cp` tells it to recurse on directories, copying its contents.

Comment: see thats the problem, i the folder i'm copying is not in the same directory as the folder i'm trying to copy too.  Both someDirA/folderTwo and someDirB are in separate paths...just like how i posted above..

Comment: @dave then just specify the paths to the directories... I will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cp` to copy files and directories:

```
cp -r /path/to/someDirA/folderTwo /path/to/someDirB
```

The `-r` option is needed when copying directories.

Alternatively, you can use `rsync`:

```
rsync -a  /path/to/someDirA/folderTwo /path/to/someDirB
```

Comment: If it's a toss-up, give the answer mark to ethanwu10: he was 30 seconds faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplification for `rsync`:

```
rsync -r someDirA/ someDirB
```

Note there is a trailing slash (/) at the end of the first argument; it is necessary to mean "the contents of `someDirA`".

Edit:

```
rsync -r --exclude 'folderOne' someDirA/ someDirB
```

Comment: The OP only wanted `folderTwo` copied.  This would also copy `folderOne`.